# How badly does failing a core class and retaking it hurt your chances at grad school programs?

Tags: graduate-admissions, undergraduate, grades

I'm sorry if this is in the wrong place.

I'm an undergraduate majoring in biology. I think, this semester, I'll fail a class on Statistics (the class is titled "Statistics for Life Sciences"). While I have the option this semester to use "Satisfactory/Unsatisfactory" and protect my GPA, this is nonetheless a failure that will show up on my transcript.

I know I messed up and I feel really bad... I could have taken an introductory Math class (an option available to those with only an AS Level in Mathematics) before taking this Statistics class and I stupidly chose not to (officially, an AS Level meets the prerequisite for this Statistics class, though most students taking it have a full A Level in Mathematics). But this is no excuse (it's officially allowed, and plenty of AS Math students succeed in this class) and I think in fact reflects worse on my judgement.  :(

I fully intend to retake this course (I can't not take it anyway; it's a core class, plus Statistics is important in Biology) and do much better in it.

How badly does this hurt my chances at a graduate school program in biology? Assuming my other biology-related classes are okay (A grades). I don't know how I'm going to explain it. I was hoping to take a research Master's, then a PhD. Am I screwed?

Thanks for any input and and have a nice day.

Comment: Biology students who have trouble with statistics are extremely common.  Retake it and devote a lot of time to it.

Comment: These systems are complicated and certainly are not fully meritocratic. Working our way through "meritocratic" systems can take several paths.

Answer (score -1):

At any stage in your career, people who will evaluate whether to give you an opportunity will (or at least *should*) be looking at multiple aspects of your CV. For each "weak" aspect there should be a "strong" aspect that offsets it. Provided this is true, you should become eligible for consideration. After that, it is often a matter of luck and the competitive nature of the opportunity.

Having said, that, there *are* places and systems which I personally know of that will *automatically* reject applications that have a *single* blemish. These places and systems are making a mistake (in my opinion). In any case, perhaps you would not want to be in a place that does not believe in giving people a second chance.

In summary, I think there are a number of good places which would give you the opportunity *if* you can counter this particular failure by something---which could even be a good grade in the same course on your second attempt.

Comment: It's not about deciding to give people chances; it's about selecting the best applicants from a pool.